# Convert UTC timestamp to another in php

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, data-conversion, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a timestamp in UTC timezone.
Example: 1600532232.
It's 4:17 PM in regular standard time.

I want to convert this timestamp to another timezone with offset and then output in regular standard time.

It should output

New york : 12:17 PM

Los Angeles : 9:17 AM

Berlin : 12:17: PM

Beijing : 11:17: PM

How do I do it in PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create a new DateTime with UTC tz
$epoch = 1600532232;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// change the timezone
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

// format the date
$dt->format('h:i A');
```